# How to set cookie using NextResponse at server side?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to set a cookie from server side using Next Response:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { config } from '@/config/config';
const GET = async () => {
    const expiration = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 300; // 5 minutes from now
    const token = jwt.sign({ exp: expiration }, config.JWT_SECRET);
    return NextResponse.json({ token }); // How do I set cookie?
};

export { GET };
```

Can someone tell me the way to set the cookie from server side using `NextResponse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This cookies instance is read-only. To set cookies, you need to return a new Response using the Set-Cookie header.

```js
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
 
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const token = cookieStore.get('token')
 
  return new Response('Hello, Next.js!', {
    status: 200,
    headers: { 'Set-Cookie': `token=${token}`},
  })
}
```

this example is from nextjs [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#dynamic-functions) so in your use case it should be:

```js
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
//...
export async function GET(request) {
  const expiration = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 300; // 5 minutes from now
  const token = jwt.sign({ exp: expiration }, config.JWT_SECRET);

  // update cookieStore
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  cookieStore.set('token', token, {
    //...
  });

  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ token }), {
    status: 200,
    headers: { 'Set-Cookie': `token=${token}`},
  });
}
```